# Lubuntu account logs into gray screen and mouse pointer, nothing else on screen

Tags: lubuntu

The main account account on my Lubuntu, as the title states, logs into a screen with nothing but the gray background and a working mouse pointer on it; no icons, no tray, no nothing... Other accounts function normal.

How the hell do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the default choice in the top right corner of the login screen changed to "Openbox." Selecting "Lubuntu" fixes the problem.